# libgdx not displaying anything

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx

Hey everyone I am really new to libgdx and Open GL so I am having trouble with this sample project I have to do. Here is my code it should be simply displaying a three buttons from a .batch file any help is greatly appreciated. After going through the debugger the only thing I could see was that the call to get draw able returned object[o] but if it didn't find anything why didn't it error out?

```
public MainScreen() {
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false, spriteBatch);
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("assets/font.fnt"),
             Gdx.files.internal("assets/font.png"), false);
    buttons = new TextureAtlas("assets/GameButtons.pack");
    images = new Skin();
    images.addRegions(buttons);
    SFXButton = new Button(images.getDrawable("sfxButton"));
    SFXButton.setPosition(295, 310);
    APIButton = new Button(images.getDrawable("apiButton"));
    APIButton.setPosition(405, 310);
    GameButton = new Button(images.getDrawable("gameButton"));
    GameButton.setPosition(515, 310);
    SFXClick = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("assets/button_click.wav"));

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    spriteBatch.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
    stage.addActor(SFXButton);
    stage.addActor(APIButton);
    stage.addActor(GameButton);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    font.setColor(Color.RED);
    font.draw(spriteBatch, "PennyPop", 455 - font.getBounds("PennpyPop").width/2, 
            460 + font.getBounds("PennyPop").height/2);
    if (SFXButton.isPressed())
        SFXClick.play();

    spriteBatch.end();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**OUCH!** *No way* you want to add buttons to your stage *every render*, with 60 FPS and 3 buttons, that would add 180 buttons to your stage *per second*, and for every second, until you close your app.

```
public void render(float delta) {
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
    stage.addActor(SFXButton); //problem here
    stage.addActor(APIButton); //and here
    stage.addActor(GameButton); //and here
```

Move the buttons adding to the constructor, see if it will solve the problem.

Comment: I see that now wow that would have been bad LOL !, thanks but its still not rendering to the screen i just get the plain white background =(

Comment: It could be by setting the camera incorrectly, or perhaps the window isn't big enough? Just to be sure it isn't something trivial like your code not being compiled properly or something, try putting some `Gdx.app.log()` in the render method to see if it is even called.

Comment: /faceplams self totally screwed up the setup and render wasnt bieng called correctly thanks for the help !!